# how to position a table in R Markdown

Tags: r-markdown, position, markdown, knitr, kableextra

I am currently creating a document in R Markdown but I cannot position a table after a particular paragraph in the pdf. My understanding is that `fig.pos="H"` can be used to position the table exactly where it is in the R Markdown.

This is how I am creating my table:

````
```{r table_1, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE, echo=FALSE, include=FALSE, fig.pos="H", fig.cap="test", out.extra=''}

library(magrittr)
library(tidyverse)
library(kableExtra)
library(readxl)
library(modelsummary)
library(scales)

tab <- matrix(c("1", "var1", "Yes","No",
                "2", "var2", "Yes","No",
                "3", "var3", "Yes","Yes",
                "4", "var4", "Yes","Yes",
                "5", "var5", "Yes","Yes"
                ), ncol=4, byrow=TRUE)
colnames(tab) <- c('#','column2','column3','column4')
rownames(tab) <- NULL
tab <- as.table(tab)

table_1_output <- kbl(tab, booktabs = T, linesep = "", row.names = 0, caption = "List of variables.") %>%
  kable_styling(font_size = 8)
```


```{r table_1_final, echo=FALSE, fig.pos="H", fig.cap="test", out.extra=''}
table_1_output
```
````

This is my R Markdown preamble:

````
---
title: '**title**'
author:
- name_author_1:
    email: email
    institute: name1
    correspondence: yes
- name: name_author_2
  institute: name2
- name: name_author_3
  institute: name2
- name: name_author_4
  institute: name3
- name: name_author_5
  institute: name3
date: "14 Nov 2022"
bibliography: ref_file.bib
bib-humanities: true
output:
  pdf_document:
    includes:
        in_header: header.tex 
    number_sections: yes
    toc: no
    pandoc_args:
    - --lua-filter=scholarly-metadata.lua
    - --lua-filter=author-info-blocks.lua
  word_document:
    toc: no
    pandoc_args:
    - --lua-filter=scholarly-metadata.lua
    - --lua-filter=author-info-blocks.lua
  html_document:
    toc: no
    df_print: paged
header-includes:
  - |
    ```{=latex}
    \makeatletter
    \DeclareRobustCommand\and{% % \begin{tabular}
      \end{tabular}%
      \hskip -.5em \@plus.17fil%
      \begin{tabular}[t]{c}}%   % \end{tabular}
    ```
institute:
- name1: name1
- name2: name2
- name3: name3
---
````

This is my `header.tex` which includes:

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{float}
\newcommand{\blandscape}{\begin{landscape}}
\newcommand{\elandscape}{\end{landscape}}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@maketitle}{\LARGE}{\Large}{\typeout{OK 1}}{\typeout{Failed 1}}
```

Do you know what I am missing?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I found a way for this to work. I added latex_options = "hold_position" as an argument to kable_styling and now the table is in the place I'd like.

Comment: I understand you have multiple outputs for various reasons, and using latex, but You can always output to HTML, with more flexible document rules, and then save as PDF from the browser, just a thought